# Синхронизирующееся Outlook-подобное приложение для Android: необходимые средства для разработки

Tags: java, android

Передо мной такая задача: разработать приложение, которой подобно Microsoft Outlook может синхронно использоваться на нескольких устройствах (телефон, стационарный компьютер, ноутбук). По назначению это приложение также подобно Outlook (для тех, кто не пользуется Outlook, скажу, что это ПО совмещает в себе электронный ежедневник, клиент электронной почты и адресную книгу), потому мотивация требований понятна: вводить разного рода записи удобнее с ПК, а вот обращаться к ним, особенно когда Вы не дома - с мобильного.

Опыта работы с Java и программирования под Android у меня пока нет, потому прошу Вас помочь составить список средств, которыми надо овладеть для выполнения поставленной задачи.

- Понятно, что в основе будет Java.
- Какие дополнительные библиотеки понадобится изучить?
- Понадобится ли писать версию для ПК (Windows) в другом языке программирования?
- Какие средства понадобятся для синхронизации между разными устройствами и OS?
- Вторичная задача: какие библиотеки Вы можете порекомендовать для создания современного графического интерфейса (как на рисунке ниже)?

[image: пример современного GUI - Arubixs Portal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для выполнения поставленной задачи вам нужно овладеть языком программирования Java и изучить [фреймворк Android](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/index.html).

Версию для ПК Windows вам понадобится писать если и не на другом языке программирования (Java-программы можно запускать на Windows), то точно под другой фреймворк, работающий на десктопе - например Swing. От кода android-приложения останется только базовая логика не связанная с взаимодействием с системой (фреймворком) - это процентов 20 кода, в лучшем случае.
Обычно же под Windows пишут на C# (олдскульные девелоперы на С++)

Для синхронизации не понадобятся "средства" - понадобятся знания. На каждой платформе есть готовые классы для выполнения синхронизации, которые вполне могут взаимодействовать межплатформенно. Из "средств" можно только выделить покупку сервера, если вы собираетесь использовать собственный, а не имеющиеся "облака".

Никаких библиотек для создания "современного интерфейса" я вам использовать не рекомендую - в android уже есть такая библиотека - [класс Widget](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/package-summary.html). Платформа Android имеет вполне четкие и очень подробные [гайдлайны](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html) по оформлению GUI, как должно выглядеть ее приложение - всякая пестрая кустарщина не приветствуется, кажется, ни на одной платформе. Пользователь платформы хочет видеть знакомый интерфейс с понятными контролами и ожидаемым поведением, принятым на этой платформе.